# 'Transforming' this $6\times 6$ complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Consider the following $6\times 6$ matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha &0&0&0&0&0\\
0 &b_{11}&0&0&b_{12}&-m_{12}\\
0 &0&m_{11}&0&0&0\\
0 &0&0&b_{22}&0&0\\
0 &b_{21}&0&0&\beta&0\\
0 &0&m_{21}&0&0&m_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix},$$

where $\alpha,\,\beta,\,b_{ij}$ and $m_{ij}$ are complex numbers, for $i,j\in\{1,2\}$.

Is it possible to 'transform' this matrix into the a matrix of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha &0&0&0&0&0\\
0 &b_{11}&b_{12}&0&0&0\\
0 &b_{21}&b_{22}&0&0&0\\
0 &0&0&m_{22}&m_{12}&0\\
0 &0&0&m_{21}&m_{11}&0\\
0 &0&0&0&0&\beta\\
\end{pmatrix}\,?$$

I have a feeling that one can do this with elementary row operations, and I have tried to obtain the latter matrix from the former in this way. However, by interchanging rows and columns, I only able to obtain the sub-matrix of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11}&b_{12}\\
b_{21}&0
\end{pmatrix},$$

with the remaining $b_{22}$ term always 'dangling' diagonally below. Can one achieve this by ERO's? Or is there something more at work here?

Am I able to get somewhere if I were to rather assume that the entries of the initial entry were all non-negative in the sense of positive-definiteness for a Hermitian matrix?

Comment: Certainly no way to do it with elementary row operations, since $$\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&\beta\end{pmatrix}$$ is the natural sub matrix. You can’t get rid of that $\beta,$ with any row operations and keep the $b_{ij}.$

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this latter matrix by some other means?

Comment: Not that I can think of, at least in terms of usual transformations. You can, of course, define any permutation on the $n^2$ matrix elements as a “transformation,” but that isn’t really a “significant” transformation.

Comment: In particular, if $\beta\neq 0$ and $b_{22}=0,$ $a_{11}\beta-a_{21}a_{12}\neq 0$ and $a_{12}a_{21}\neq 0$ then the two matrices have different rank, which is not common using most notions of transformation. Likewise if $a_{22},\beta\neq 0$ and $a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}=0$ and $a_{11}\beta-a_{12}a_{21}\neq 0,$ again the two matrices have different rank.

Comment: I had removed one row and one column (each entirely of 0's) - might this have had this affect?

Comment: I'll edit my question with more entries and information, and see if this makes it clearer.

Comment: Using elementary row operations (swap column 3 with column 5, then swap row 3 with row 5) you should get the following:

\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha &0&0&0&0\\
0 &b_{11}&b_{12}&0&0\\
0 &b_{21}&\beta&0&0\\
0 &0&0&b_{22}&0\\
0 &0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}

That's just the way it is. Your $b_{22}$ is independent while $\beta$ is not.

Comment: With Linear Algebra you have to remember that entries of a Matrix that share a row (or share a column) have some interdependent relationship to one another.


This means that in your (now 6x6) matrix, $\alpha$ has no relation to any other entries, and neither does $b_{22}$.  However, $b_{11}$ is interdependent with $b_{12}$ and $b_{21}$ while both of those are also dependent on $\beta$.  Similarly, $m_{11}$ is interdependent with $m_{21}$ which is to $m_{22}$ which is to $m_{12}$ (which in turn is related to $b_{12}$ unless there was a typo and it should actually be in the $m_{11}$ row).

Comment: All this is to say that our proposed solution cannot be valid because it clearly doesn't correctly preserve the $b_{22}$ independence of the original, nor does it show all of the $\beta$ interdependencies. (The $m$ interdependencies might be fine, assuming that $m_{12}$ is typo'd and actually supposed to be in the $m_{11}$ row; if it's not a typo then there is a lot of $b$-$m$ interdependencies that are being ignored in your proposed matrix.)

Comment: It's not a typo - it's something I also found quite odd. I have followed everything you have said, and the point you are making is clear. Are you able to see what the 'best' (block) diagonalisation is? If you made this an answer, I'd be happy to accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the 6x6 matrix we are working with:
$$
\mathbf{M} = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha &0&0&0&0&0\\
0 &b_{11}&0&0&b_{12}&-m_{12}\\
0 &0&m_{11}&0&0&0\\
0 &0&0&b_{22}&0&0\\
0 &b_{21}&0&0&\beta&0\\
0 &0&m_{21}&0&0&m_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
there are a number of operations we can do to try to make this matrix easier to work with.  The first operation that we're going to try involves some elementary row (and column) swapping.  The cleanest way to do this is by defining a Unitary Matrix; the simplest choice of which (for our specific example) might be:
$$
\mathbf{U} = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has the properties $\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^{\ast}=\mathbf{U}^{\ast}\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{I}$ (where $\mathbf{U}^{\ast}$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $\mathbf{U}$) and $\det(\mathbf{U})=1$. This means (thanks to the identity $\det(\mathbf{AB})=\det(\mathbf{A})\det(\mathbf{B})$ used repeatedly) that we can creat a transformed matrix $\mathbf{T}=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{M}\mathbf{U}^{\ast}$ which will have $\det(\mathbf{T})=\det(\mathbf{M})$ which should make computing eigenvalues easier if we made a good choice of $\mathbf{U}$.  If we put all of the above together, we have:
$$
\mathbf{T} = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha&0&0&0&0&0\\
0 &b_{22}&0&0&0&0\\
0 &0&b_{11}&b_{12}&0&-m_{12}\\
0 &0&b_{21}&\beta&0&0\\
0 &0&0&0&m_{11}&0\\
0 &0&0&0&m_{21}&m_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is as simple as we can get things via basic transformations.  Fortunately, the above is a (Block) Upper Triangular matrix so it shouldn't be too difficult to calculate determinants or eigenvalues from here.